# Filereader gets overwritten when multiple files are active

Tags: jquery, loops, parsing, filereader, html5-filesystem

I'm trying to parse 2 or more xml files at once. Means I can choose for example 5 .xml files, then it should get parsed via jQuery plugin and written on the page afterwards.
Now my problem: The second, third etc. iteration of the loop fires too early so the first file gets "lost".

My attempt:

```
var input = $("#xmlInput");
input.change(function () {
   var inputfiles = input[0].files;
   for (var i = 0; i < inputfiles.length; i++) {
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.readAsText(inputfiles[i]);
      reader.onloadend = function () {
         var data = $.xml2json(reader.result);
         console.log(data);
         //write(data);
      }
    }
 });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer on an other so question:

```
(function (file) {
   var reader = new FileReader();
   reader.onload = function (readerData) {
      var data = $.xml2json(readerData.target.result);
      write(data);
   }
   reader.readAsText(file);
})(inputfiles[i]);
```

Works like a charm. =)

Answer (score 0):

its just a guess but does it help to assign FileReader to different variables ?

```
   var temp = {};

   var input = $("#xmlInput");
   input.change(function () {
      var inputfiles = input[0].files;
      for (var i = 0; i < inputfiles.length; i++) {
         temp["reader"+i] = new FileReader();
         temp["reader"+i].readAsText(inputfiles[i]);
         temp["reader"+i].onloadend = function () {
            var data = $.xml2json(temp["reader"+i].result);
            console.log(data);
            //write(data);
         }
       }
    });
```

Comment: Thx for helping but "temp["reader"+i].result" returns undefined, any idea why?